# Is it possible to have different languages in Symfony2 (example.com/fr/page) but also default to example.com/page for English?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to find a way to setup Symfony2 with language support but where it defaults to a default language if a language not entered.

So basically I want to allow these URLs for the 'page' page:

```
example.com/page
example.com/fr/page
example.com/de/page
```

etc...

I can easily do it if you always specify a language (e.g. example.com/en/page) but I don't want that. I want my links to be like this for English:

```
example.com
example.com/page
example.com/about
```

...and IF the user changes language to then append that to the URL:

```
example.com/fr
example.com/fr/page
example.com/fr/about
```

I currently use this but I have to specify a language on every request:

```
the_site:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    requirements:
     _locale: en|fr|es|de
```

I don't think this is possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle). Scenario #2 (described [in the docs](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration#scenario-prefixing-all-routes-with-the-locale-except-those-of-the-default-locale)) is what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Is it not possible by default with Symfony2? I don't need any other features of that bundle at all just this one tiny thing.

Comment: I think it's not... of course you can add your own listener and copy code from the bundle (or implement it yourself), but I think it doesn't worth the hassle...